# How to correctly implement inheritance in TypeScript in this particular case?

Tags: typescript

I'm rather new to TypeScript and I've come around to this situation where I have the following interface defined in my application:

```
export interface Car {
  brand: string;
  optionalField?: string;
  [.... other optional fields, no functions defined ...]
}
```

and it is passed around as argument to some functions in a few places in my application as anonymous instances, as such:

```
someFunctionCall({
 brand: "Toyota",
 [...other relevant fields]
});
```

Now, there has come a time when I would like to add a new field to my interface, let's call it `type` which is mandatory and at this moment can have two possible values (`Suv` and `Sedan`), but in the future will extend to others (such as `Pickup`, `Hatchback` and so on).

Let's assume all my method calls at this moment concern `Suv` cars.

I was hoping I would be able to add this new field to the Car interface and create two distinct interfaces for Suv and Sedan where I could define a default value for the newly added field and call the methods with something like:

```
someFunctionCall({
  brand: "Toyota",
  [...other relevant fields]
} as Suv);
```

but I noticed that there can not be any default values defined in an interface.

Is there a better way than going through all places where these new objects of type `Car` are instantiated and manually adding the `type: "Suv"` parameter to them?
Can this be achieved by using interfaces / classes / abstract classes?

Please share your thoughts.

Thank you!

Comment: Presumably you are already manually writing `as Suv` and `as Sedan` everywhere, which doesn’t work (the TS type system is erased when transpiled to JS so this can’t work).  Can you articulate why replacing that with actual valid `type` properties would be worse?  Even if we refactor to classes you’ll still have to manually write `new Suv( … )` in all the same places. What am I missing?

Comment: @jcalz I think I find it more clear the proposed way. Also I think there is less code duplicate and the resulting code blocks will be smaller and cleaner.

Comment: What “proposed way”? Using class constructors? Using type assertions?